# Assign a ListDigraph::ArcMap to a class attribute into a constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, graph, lemon-graph-library

I need the following:

- create a class which does something with a graph
- the modification on the graph and the related maps must be possible in different functions, so that all of them can change the global state of graph and maps
- I have both graph and maps as attribute variable, and I want to define the map in the constructor, so I can create it when I create the object.

The problem is that I cannot assign to a class attribute a map. the error I get is the following:

```
'operator=' is a private member of 'lemon::DigraphExtender<lemon::ListDigraphBase>::ArcMap<int>'
```

when I try the assignment: `this->length = ListDigraph::ArcMap<int>(g);`

`length` and `g`  are declared as public attributes of the class:

```
ListDigraph g;
ListDigraph::ArcMap<int> length;
```

Comment: rather than repeatedly asking questions about the same issue you should clarify one of the questions, by adding a [mcve] and the relevant details. Though, if the type has no accessible `operator=` then you cannot call its `operator=` no matter how hard you try

Comment: constructors should not assign to members. A constructor should initialize members

Comment: I cannot initialize the ArcMap after its declaration, that is the problem

Comment: "I cannot initialize the ArcMap after its declaration, that is the problem" it is unclear what you mean by that. To get help with non-working code you need to show a [mcve] of the code

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is in one of the question you already cited, that does not get answer